# Display image from IMAGE object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an object of type IMAGE which holds image.
I wanted to display the image in MVC view along with other controls.
The way i can think of is to temporary store image on disk and set src of img control.
I am sure there would be better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a handler to stream images out and then reference the streamer in your image tag.

For instance, you have http://myapp/media.ashx?imageId=10 stream out the image.  In your page you reference like so: 
`<img src="http://myapp/media.ashx?imageId=10"/>`.

This way you don't have to temporarily write to disk.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion would be to return a `FileStreamResult` from your controller.

```
public FileResult GetImage()
{
    string path = "c:\images\image.jpg";
    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
}
```

This is a simple implementation, but gives you a starting point for what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in implementing [@Giovanni's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379614/display-image-from-image-object-in-mvc/1379651#1379651) answer, then I have some code that may be helpful from a past answer I gave located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control/46801#46801).  The ImageHandler class is an example of what you would want to implement in Giovanni's case.

Answer (score 1):

You can serve your image as the response content of a controller action. this response will have the image type as content type.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image to Base64 string and assign it to the src attribute of the img tag.

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" width="168" height="32" 
  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKgA..." />
```

http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64