# Displaying images from collection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a collection of custom type which is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class PhotoDC
{
    public PhotoDC();

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] ImagebyteArray { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show all the items (image and name) on a web form , any idea which control I can use and how can I convert byte array to image ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in control in ASP.NET that you can directly assign a byte array to display images. What you can do is, simply write a custom HttpHandler that takes "Name" as an argument and sends the byte array as a binary response to the client with appropriate http response headers.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomImageHandler.aspx) is an example of custom http handler. In this sample image is built from a file using a file stream.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Repeater` control that has a label and Image controls with the Item template.

The following converts to and from and byteArray.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an Image to Byte array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imageIn">Image to convert</param>
    /// <returns>byte array</returns>
    public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an Byte array to and Image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="byteArrayIn">byre array</param>
    /// <returns>Image</returns>
    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        var returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control) shows you have to bind Memory stream to asp.net image control.