# ASP.NET MS Chart can I use Http Handler to Read and Write the Tempory Image from a web service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, httphandler, mschart, web-farm

My application is deployed to a web farm that does not use sticky sessions (unfortunately this is not an option). I would like to write the chart image to a web service and read it from there as the client browser does not always get redirected to the same server the image has been rendered to. I cannot use a file server due to security restrictions and do not have access to a database from the IIS service directly only to a wcf service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are asking:

client -> WS Call -> ?? -> HTTPHandler that generates chart?

I'm not sure why you need the web service part.

You can use an HTTPHandler to generate the image this can work really well. Just instantiate your chart object and write it to the output stream.

Some sample code about saving to a stream from the nets.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
//Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.png"); // You only want this to save as attachment
Chart4.SaveImage(Response.OutputStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);        
Response.End();
```

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. I found the following links useful http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/093009-1.aspx    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control .I created a page that returns a memory stream created from the MS Chart control then added an asp:image with a ImageUrl of my previous page. I didn't need to store the image chart behind a web service

Comment: Yeah sounds good. One thing I would add is that with a page you have the full overhead of the page lifecycle whereas with an HTTPHandler you of course don't - hence why its the preferred method for implementing custom images etc. Depends on your requirements though.