# Image With Asp.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with Images I have a image which is at root directory like “C:\Mh\mahesh1” and tried to upload by following ways but won’t works.

```
Defaults.aspx.cs 
namespace UITI
{
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string img = MapPath("~Mh/mahesh1.jpg");
        myimages.ImageUrl = img;
    }
   }
 }

 Defaults.aspx
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"           Inherits="UITI._Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
 <title>Untitled Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
 <asp:Image ID="myimages" runat="server"  BorderStyle="Double" />
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I have also tried on Default.aspx.cs page like:

```
namespace UITI
{
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string img = ResolveClientUrl ("~/Mh/mahesh1.jpg");   
        myimages.ImageUrl = img;
    }
  }
 }
```

How to do?.

Comment: See my below Edited code,and try that

Comment: okay try this.Dont put any folder name.See my new Edit


ResolveUrl("mahesh1.jpg")

Comment: okay .Rename your mahesh1 image and try again ..please see your problem in my post

Comment: See the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/46788/447356). You need to read the file from server disk as you don't have any URL to assign.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
string img = Server.MapPath("~/Mh/mahesh1.jpg");
    myimages.ImageUrl = img;
```

or

**Edit**:

```
string img = ResolveUrl("~/Mh/mahesh1.jpg");

myimages.ImageUrl = img;
```

If it not worked,please check your folder path `(~/Mh/mahesh1.jpg)`. Your path is non correct. My above code is working to me

**New Edit**

```
string img = **ResolveUrl("mahesh1.jpg");**

myimages.ImageUrl = img;
```

**See**
first just try this for put  correct url straightly

```
**myimages.ImageUrl = @"~/Mh/mahesh1";**
```

**Problem is here:**
Your mahesh1 image is inside of any other folder(for project folder or any other drive or desktop ) .So you got this problem  . You can use any other image. or rename of your mahesh1 to mahes123 (if you  like name) image  then check.

Comment: Use ResolveUrl . Its working . See my above Edited code,and try that

Comment: Check your path  .Please open your image and not the path .check it. Code is correct.

Comment: I have a three images in "C:\Mh\Image1670 , Image1672 and mahesh1 all are jpeg images. The path is correct but don't know how it is not working?.

Comment: okay try this.Dont put any folder name.See my new Edit


ResolveUrl("mahesh1.jpg")

Comment: If such thing is not working for me than is it possible for technical error in my application or any bug in my application?.

Comment: Change your project path . for Desktop to any inside of folder


Copy your project  then past any folder(not desktop)   for F G E D. Then run your application

Comment: Again it's not working for me. Some thing wrong in my application.

Comment: Change your project path . for Desktop to any inside of folder Copy your project then past any folder(not desktop) for F G E D. Then run your application

if you checked this??

Comment: I have created hello folder on desktop and paste mahesh1.jpeg file on it and tried your "ResloveUrl("Mahesh1.jpg"); but it won't works....

Comment: No No.. Don't create your project in desktop. Create Your local folder for E D F G  Drives .any one

Comment: I don't have IIS installed on my machine. Is such problem due to unavailable of IIS?.

Comment: I have created "A" Folder on C:\ Drive and paste mahesh1 on it but same problem again it's not working.

Comment: hey first use this


myimages.ImageUrl = @"~/Mh/mahesh1";

see my another Edit

Comment: also tried by changing drives from c:\ to E:\ but it's won't affect

Comment: okay leave it. now  should try it

okay leave it. now  should try it

myimages.ImageUrl = @"~/Mh/mahesh1";

Comment: Sorry It's not works but I have checked @"C:\A\Mah.jpg"; and it's works but still I have a question why it's not works as above what's wrong with it?.

Comment: I think .Your mahesh1 image is inside of any other folder .So you got his problem ..

Comment: No. No I am 100% sure the path given is correct here something wrong which I can't see but what is it?.

Comment: okay .Rename your mahesh1 image and try again ..please see your problem in my post