# Saving and retrieving of images from SQL Server database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image, sql-server-2005

I have created a web page where I have used `Image` control to display the image. Along with this control I have some labels and input box also

Below is the code which I have used to save the image to database

```
byte[] imageSize = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
HttpPostedFile uploadedImage = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
uploadedImage.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

SqlParameter UploadedImage = new SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.Image, imageSize.Length);
UploadedImage.Value = imageSize;

string sql = "insert into imageDB(Image) values (@image)";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add(UploadedImage);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and below is the code I have used to retrieve the image from database

```
byte[] rawImg = (byte[])rdr["image"];
MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream();
Stream.Write(rawImg, 0, rawImg.Length);
Bitmap Display_Picture = new Bitmap(Stream);
//after this no idea how to proceed
```

I have read some links all are suggesting we can not set this byte information to `Image` control.

Let me know if my way of retrieving the image from data base is right, if its right, what type of control I should use, so that image which has been retrieved from database can be displayed on web page

Answer (score 1):

**Is my way of retrieving the image from database right?**

I would use the following code instead (sorry not tested):

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(rdr["image"]);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

**How do I bind the image to an asp.net image control?**

I would create an HttpHandler which gets and returns the image. Then bind the ImageUrl property on the asp:Image to the url of the HttpHandler.
How you can do this you can see in the answer of Dale Ragan over here: [How to bind a MemoryStream to asp:image control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control)

Answer (score 0):

First, in your example your have to reset the Position inside your stream to 0: `Stream.Position = 0;`

Second, you have to write your image to a local cache folder of your web service that is part of your web application. You image control can have a Source-reference (img.src) to the address of that image.

Or... you can create an AXD-file / HttpHandler. An AXD file is a file, just like an ASPX, but specialized in returning any type of data, like an image.

For more info, see: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/using-httphandlers-to-serve-image-files

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve image, and show on asp.net Image control, you can

```
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from ImageCollection where img_id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", cn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {

            string image1 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(image1, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
            byte[] bimage1 = (byte[])dr["passport_photo"];
            fs1.Write(bimage1, 0, bimage1.Length - 1);
            fs1.Flush();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

*Alternative solution:*

Implement a handler to serve the image. Have a look at the [System.Web.IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) interface.

The idea would be to write an image tag in your page along the lines of:

```
<asp:image runat="server" imageurl="~/Image.ashx?ID=xxx" />
```

Then in your handler implementation, get the id from the querystring, retrieve the image as you're already doing and then write directly to the response stream.

Comment: Can I know what is this DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString(); from this code how i will come to know what is the file name with which image is stored

Comment: I tried this solutuion, I am finding images are getting stored in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE" in this path. whatever path you hardcode, still images are getting stored in this path. I tried to set Image1.imageUrl with this path and still not seeing image on webpage