# Set asp:Image picture from System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have database with Image field, and `asp:FileUpload` on the page. Method for save image is

```
protected void btnUploadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream str = uplReportImage.FileContent;
    //записать в файл   
    ViewHolder.CurrentTemplate.HeaderLogo = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(str);
}
```

So, in my `ViewHolder` I have `System.Drawing.Image` field. How can I set it to `asp:Image` control?

Comment: You need to save your image somewhere and then use an URL to access it

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control), you can use handler to return image and set handler url to image control url property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a HttpHandler that fetched the image from a specific url. You can use the url in your pages, and fetch it in the http handler.

This has advantages when browsers cache images, and you can reuse the image easily on different pages.

Answer (score 1):

The control has an ImageUrl property which can be set to a unique GUID to a server-side handler, which can parse the GUID and dynamically write the contents of System.Drawing.Image as Response.BinaryWrite by setting an appropriate mime type.