# How do I display Dropbox image files in an ASP.NET web page using Core API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to show Dropbox image files in an ASP.NET image control using the Core API in C#. I'm populating the dropbox image file using the below code:

```
RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Get
(
    "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/",
    new HttpParameterCollection
    {
        { "path", "FilePath" },
        { "access_token", "AccessToken" }
    }
);
```

Suppose there is an image control on the .aspx page

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server">
```

and I want to display the Dropbox image file on this control.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control. I think you need to create an `HttpHandler`. The Dropbox part of this should be no different from using any other content for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial link was incorrect, instead of:

```
dropbox.com/1/metadata/
```

The following link should have been used:

```
dropboxapi.com/1/media/
```

Comment: This answer is excessively brief and hard to understand. Please flesh it out so it is more clear what you are suggesting as an answer.